why get error copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars FAILED when building application speech by react-native-voice_voice?
I'm a beginner in React Native. My application is about recognization speech users. Everything is Ok when I build application by command npx react-native run-android. But I get error copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars FAILED when build file apk by command cd android && .\gradlew assembleRelease. I try to clean gradle by command cd android && .\gradlew clean but it's not better. Can you help me to solve it.
Thanks!
Have a great day.
